# Does Electrum receive BTC as well as mBTC? Or are they the same thing?

Tags: wallet, electrum

I notice that electrum works with mBTC, but I wanted to set up a BTC wallet. Are they the same thing, or interchangeable? I'm fairly new to wallets, so I apologize if this is a very easy or stupid question.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An mBTC is just 0.001 BTC, like a cent is 0.01 dollar.

Comment: Okay, thank you. The wallet balance is recorded in mBTC, so that means it's still bitcoin but quantified differently, correct?

Comment: This is the same as asking whether the gas price is 2.53 $ per gallon or 253 cents per gallon. Both are equally correct, they're just different representations of the same thing. If you configure Electrum to show amounts in mBTC, it'll show mBTC. It can probably also show it in satoshis (0.00000001 BTC) or bits (0.000001 BTC) or BTC itself.

Comment: Ah okay great, thank you. I was under the impression they were entirely different currencies, I apologize if it was a dumb question

Comment: There are no dumb questions, I'm happy it was easy to clarify.